# How to write sentence in notepad using keyboard python package

Tags: python

I want to write the output in a separate notepad or ms word using python package [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

```
  import keyboard
  keyboard.write('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
```

but it writes these sentence in the command prompt, where I run the script, not in notepad. 
How can I make it to control the other software?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your other application focus.

When searching for a method I found this blog post which shows how it can done in Windows:

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/

```
import win32gui

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = []
    top_windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)
    for i in top_windows:
        if "notepad" in i[1].lower():
            print i
            win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
            break
```

After the application has focus, you can use your simulated key presses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pywinauto` package which is more efficient and friendly:

```py
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start('notepad.exe')

# describe the window inside Notepad.exe process
window = app.UntitledNotepad # or app['Untitled - Notepad'], its the same
# wait till the window is really open
window_ready = window.wait('visible')


# Write in some text
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("Hello world", with_spaces = True)
```

NOTE: Some lines are adapted from [the documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)